# Is it possible to restart a server without access to its SSL key?

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache-2.4, user-permissions

I'm given a server (with root access) by a tech department to run a web-app app on some sub-domain. But the app requires authenification. So I requested the SSL key for the domain. The tech squad is reluctant to give me the key -- this is understandable.

I need to restart the server from time to time. Is it possible to configure permissions for a non-root user to be able to restart the server, but with no access to it's SSL key?

The server might be either of apache or nginx. If I run either of two with no root access I get the following:

- apache:

  ```
  AH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/canvas-misis-ru.conf:
  SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' does not exist or is empty
  ```
- nginx:

  ```
  nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
  2014/09/21 17:08:55 [warn] 16805#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
  2014/09/21 17:08:55 [emerg] 16805#0: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key','r') error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib)
  ```

Comment: You should not start apache/nginx process under another user than root so they can impersonate user/group defined in their config files and read config files owned by root. A common solution is to create a nopassword SSL key only readable for root and allow users to `sudo` a daemon manager to gracefully restart apache or nginx processes.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to grant root-rights for a single command to a user using a rule in `/etc/sudoers`.

- Do `sudo visudo`
- Add a new rule

  ```
  someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
  ```

As you can see, it is possible to also parameters.

The user `someuser` is the allowed to do the following:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Suppose I'd like to run `apt-get install` with no password. What is the correct rule than?

Comment: Seems like it is `someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install` -- so no `/sbin` binaries are possible, and full path is due.

Comment: `/usr/sbin` is possible. And full absolute paths are mandatory, yes.